# Ajax Request 500 Internal Server Error in Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net, json, internet-explorer, jquery

I am getting this `500 Internal Server Error` only in IE 10 when I run my application that makes a simple Ajax request to a Page Method. I have tested it in Chrome and Firefox, it works fine in these. Please make any relevant suggestion ASAP.
I will paste the code below:

```
        function GetProductId() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/GenerateQrCode",
            data: "{'Products':" + JSON.stringify([{ ProductId: 1 }, { ProductId: 2 }]) + "}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(xhr.responseText);
                alert(thrownError);
            },
            success: function (msg) {
                var data = $.parseJSON(msg.d);
            }
        });
    }
```

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string GenerateQrCode(List<Product> Products)
    {
        List<string> images = new List<string>();

        foreach(var product in Products)
        {
            string qrCodeLocation = (from pic in products
                                    where pic.ProductId == product.ProductId
                                    select pic.QrCode).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
            images.Add(qrCodeLocation);
        }

        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return js.Serialize(images);
    }
```

Comment: What's the error generated on the server?

Comment: Don't know what you mean exactly. But I cannot hit the breakpoint if placed inside the Page Method. Only in case of Internet Explorer.

Comment: Maybe you are referring to this error message: `Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027Products\u0027` ....keeps on going.

Comment: when generating json data you shouldn't manually create it, so use `JSON.stringify({Products : [ { ProductId : 1 }, { Productd : 2 } ]});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is a bug of .Net framework:

IE10 is not mapped as IE browser, and ASP.NET throw back the JS code for a generic browser.

Add this meta-tag in the top of your master page and try again:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
```